# Disabling the shadow around JInternalFrames with the Aqua Look and Feel

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel, jinternalframe

On Mac OS X with the native Aqua Look and Feel, JInternalFrames have a shadow that is part of the frame border. When the internal frame is maximized, the shadow is still visible and takes a lot of space.

Is there a way to remove this shadow without switching to another look and feel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the Aqua L&F code in OpenJDK I found an undocumented property that let you change the style of an internal frame. Shadows can be removed with this:

```
internalFrame.putClientProperty("JInternalFrame.frameType", "normal");
```

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/macosx-port/macosx-port/jdk/file/087d8f180711/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/laf/AquaInternalFrameUI.java

Answer (score 1):

Swing makes it relatively easy to create your own Border classes. The Swing set does that by providing a base class named `AbstractBorder`. The `AbstractBorder` class can be a good starting point for creating customized borders for Swing components.

you can easily override the installation of a UI-default border for the component by simply setting your own Border object using the setBorder() method.

For more details see this : [Understanding borders](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/borders/index.html#Defaults)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that would remove the whole border. If possible I'd like to remove just the shadow and preserve the style of the frame border. Writing a custom border is unlikely to look like the native one.

Comment: I'm not sure if thats possible! Hope someone else will answer :))